# How to calculate natural logarithm in the Windows 10 calculator app?

Tags: windows, windows-10, calculator

How can I calculate logn (or ln) in the official Microsoft Windows 10 Calculator app?

[image: The official calculator app in Windows 10]

Comment: notice the ↑ arrow on the left of CE

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is a keyboard shortcut.  In Scientific mode, <kbd>N</kbd> gives you natural log.  Lots of other shortcuts here: [Microsoft Support](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/13805).

Another option is to download the free [Calculator Plus](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/p/calculator-plus/9wzdncrdhjwd?activetab=pivot:overviewtab) from the Microsoft store.  That has dedicated buttons for an extensive range of things, including <kbd>ln</kbd>:

[image]

BTW, it also has an option for the "Classic View", which looks like the earlier Windows calculators.

Answer (score 4):

The easiest way is to **maximize the calculator** (as you maximize any window). Once you do that, some additional options are added to the calculator, including the *ln* function.

[image: This is how it looks]

Comment: you just need to resize the calculator to make it big enough. No need to maximize

Answer (score 4):

If the window size is small then just like pocket scientific calculators, secondary options will be put in a state accessible with the <kbd>Shift ⇧</kbd> key, i.e. the <kbd>↑</kbd> arrow button beside CE, above <kbd>π</kbd>

After you press <kbd>↑</kbd> then the functions will be inverted. The base will be switched from **10** to **e**. That means *10<sup>x</sup>* and *log* become *e<sup>x</sup>* and *ln* respectively

[image: small calculator shift key demo]

The more you expand the window, the more space and buttons it'll have, and those options will be available directly without shifting

Answer (score 0):

Maybe they added later but it's working
[image]